# Real Analysis: Continuity

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, epsilon-delta

$f(x)=\left\{ x^2+x, x \in  \Bbb Q\right\}, f(x)=\left\{ x^3 + 1, x \notin \Bbb Q \right\}$

I want to prove that $f$ is discontinuous at $x \ne 1$.

What I have so far is:

Fix $\delta > 0$. We need to find an $\epsilon > 0$ s.t.  $|f(x)-f(p)| \geq \epsilon$, $\forall |x-p| < \delta, p \ne 1$.

Consider $p \in \Bbb Q$, $x \notin \Bbb Q$. Then, $|f(x)-f(p)|=|(x^3+1-p^2-p)|$. We need to find an $\epsilon(\delta, p)$ s.t. $0<|x-p|<\delta \implies |(x^3+1-p^2-p)| \geq \epsilon$.

I think I need to algebraically manipulate the left side of the equation so that I can pull out a $|x-p|$, which would give epsilon as a function of delta and $p$. However, I can't seem to find how to do this.

Comment: Do you mean $f$ a function with domain $\mathbb{R}$ and $f(x) = x^2 + x$, when $x$ is rational and $x^3+1$ when it isn't?

Comment: @Mr.Rager You will have problems doing that, because $x^3-x^2-x+1$ has two roots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $a$ be a continuity point of $f$. Since rational and irrationls are dense in $\mathbb{R}$, let $(q_n)$ and $(r_n)$ be sequences of rationals and irrationals, respectively, converging to $a$. Then by continuity
\begin{equation}
\lim_\limits{n\to \infty}f(q_n) =  \lim_\limits{n\to \infty}f(r_n), 
\end{equation}
i.e.,
\begin{equation}
a^2+a = a^3 + 1.
\end{equation}
But you can see that the polynomial $a^3-a^2-a+1$ has only two real roots, namely, $1$ and $-1$, and this shows that $f$ is discontinuous at $x\neq \pm1$.